# What do DECLSPEC and SDLCALL mean in a function definition in a header file on Linux mean?

Tags: c, linux, sdl

I was poking around the SDL 2 header files, and found that the majority of functions that I encountered had this form:

```
extern DECLSPEC int SDLCALL SDL_FunctionName();
```

I understand what `extern`, `int`, and `SDL_FunctionName` all mean (the storage class specifier, return value, and function name, respectively).  However, I must admit that I have not seen the likes of `DECLSPEC` and `SDLCALL` before.  Searches for the former merely yield a Win32/64 API thing, and nothing good comes up for the latter.

What do these two things mean, and what do they *do*?

Answer (score 6):

These are constants defined to change the export behavior of a symbol (the function) by the C/C++ compiler.

`DECLSPEC` is a macro used in C/C++ header files. It stands for either `__declspec(dllexport)` or `__declspec(dllimport)` depending on whether you are the project library or the consumer. See [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa271769%28v=vs.60%29.aspx) for more details.

1. **In the declaring/owning project** of the class, `DECLSPEC` resolves to `__declspec(dllexport)`. This tells the compiler to allow access to these functions from outside the DLL. It also changes the default naming behavior of the compiler (called *name decoration* or *name mangling*) to allow easier access to these symbols from outside the DLL. See [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa278950%28v=vs.60%29.aspx).
2. **In the consuming project**, `DECLSPEC` resolves to `__declspec(dllimport)`. This is not strictly necessary, but its use allows the compiler to generate more efficient code for the consumed symbols, such as in generation of thunks. See [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa279230%28v=vs.60%29.aspx).

`SDLCALL` would be a constant which declares the calling convention of the function. You can read more about calling conventions such as `__stdcall`, `__cdecl`, etc. [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/984x0h58.aspx).

These macros are used to make the program portable across many different architectures and platforms, just by redefining the constants. Usually, the compiler or SDK used on the platform has these macros globally defined.

Answer (score 2):

> SDLCALL

`SDLCALL` would be [calling convention](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Calling_convention) that this function should be implemented. This tells who pushes arguments to the function (caller or callee) and who clears the stack when function returns.

MSDN has some detail info [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/984x0h58.aspx) about different calling conventions.

> DECLSPEC

Signifies that this function can be candidate for exported function. Its mainly used in Windows to export a function from DLL.

Comment: Interesting.  Do you have any idea where I might find the calling conventions for SDL?

Answer (score 2):

If you look in SDL's headers you'll find `begin_code.h` which has the following snippet to define `DECLSPEC`:

```
/* Some compilers use a special export keyword */
#ifndef DECLSPEC
# if defined(__WIN32__) || defined(__WINRT__)
#  ifdef __BORLANDC__
#   ifdef BUILD_SDL
#    define DECLSPEC
#   else
#    define DECLSPEC    __declspec(dllimport)
#   endif
#  else
#   define DECLSPEC __declspec(dllexport)
#  endif
# else
#  if defined(__GNUC__) && __GNUC__ >= 4
#   define DECLSPEC __attribute__ ((visibility("default")))
#  elif defined(__GNUC__) && __GNUC__ >= 2
#   define DECLSPEC __declspec(dllexport)
#  else
#   define DECLSPEC
#  endif
# endif
#endif
```

and `SDLCALL`:

```
/* By default SDL uses the C calling convention */
#ifndef SDLCALL
#if (defined(__WIN32__) || defined(__WINRT__)) && !defined(__GNUC__)
#define SDLCALL __cdecl
#else
#define SDLCALL
#endif
#endif /* SDLCALL */
```

So it looks like for Linux, `DECLSPEC` will be defined to:

```
__attribute__ ((visibility("default")))
```

or

```
__declspec(dllexport)
```

depending on the version of GCC being used and `SDLCALL` will be defined to nothing.

on other platforms, those macros may have different definitions depending on the needs of the particular platform and compiler being used.

Answer (score 1):

They are preprocessor definitions. They are used to make the code cross platform, as DLL modifiers are required on Windows. When the library is being built as a DLL on Windows, it is defined as `__declspec(dllexport)` so the function is externally visible. When the headers are being used by an application linked to the DLL on Windows, it is defined as `__declspec(dllimport)` so the compiler knows to look for it in an external DLL. See the source code [here](http://www.libsdl.org/tmp/docs-1.2/begin__code_8h-source.html) to see exactly how they are defined.

Answer (score 1):

Here's the GCC wiki page on visibility. http://gcc.gnu.org/wiki/Visibility

Shared libraries contain a list of all the symbols (names of functions and variables) that can be accessed from linking applications. On Linux the default behavior has long been to expose (store in a list in the shared library) all defined symbols, whether they are needed or not. With the new visibility feature and an extra compiler flag only the needed symbols are in this list, making a smaller, faster-to-link shared library.

The GCC wiki page focuses on C++ where the gains are most dramatic but the feature works for C too.

That's for `DECLSPEC`. On Linux `SDLCALL` does nothing but when it is defined it is used to say the functions should use the C calling convention.